SQL fetch values of goods and categories from one column and past them in two diferent
This is the table goodsandcat



Item
Key




Electronics
0


Smartphones
1


Laptops
1


Cameras
1


Headphones
1


Clothing
0


T-shirts
1


Jeans
1


Dresses
1


Jackets
1



Column Item has names of categories and goods with their respective 0 and 1 in column Key.
It is required to fetch all categories and goods into two diferent columns like Goods and Categories. So, every goods-item must have its respective category-item in each row.
I tried to do this SQL
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Key = 0 THEN Item ELSE NULL END AS Category,
    CASE WHEN Key = 1 THEN Item ELSE NULL END AS Goods
FROM goodsandcat;

The resul of the query was:



Category
Goods




Electronics
NULL


NULL
Smartphones


NULL
Laptops


NULL
Cameras


NULL
Headphones


Clothing
NULL


NULL
T-shirts


NULL
Jeans


NULL
Dresses


NULL
Jackets



But it is expected to fill out by respective category-item all NULLs in column Category. So, it must be like this:



Category
Goods




Electronics
NULL


Electronics
Smartphones


Electronics
Laptops


Electronics
Cameras


Electronics
Headphones


Clothing
NULL


Clothing
T-shirts


Clothing
Jeans


Clothing
Dresses


Clothing
Jackets



How to write sql-query fo getting above mentioned result?

The question does not make sense as asked. Unlike flat text files, relational databases do not have inherent row ordering, so there's no relationship between Electronics and Smartphones as you seem to think. Voting to close.

Does your table actually have any other columns? Specifically, anything you could put in an ORDER BY to deterministicly get the ordering in your question?

Agreeing with the previous comment.  This is not like a spreadsheet, where You can create a relationship based on the position within the sheet.
Instead, if you have a key for each row, you may be able to find a query that will group them, then build your query.
What I've done with things like this is drop it into a spreadsheet then create a query/view that will insert things into the DB, something like:
Column A Contains the Items list, Column B contains the Keys then
Column C contains this formula:
=IF(B2=0,A2,C1)
Column D contains this formula:
=IF(B2=1,A2,"NULL")
Then Column E contains this formulas:
="INSERT INTO Item_Table (Category, Goods) VALUES ('" & C2 & "', '" & D2 & "');"
Your result in column E will be formulas you can paste into your DB to create the table you want.
e.g.


INSERT INTO goodsandcat (Category, Goods) VALUES ('Electronics', 'NULL');
INSERT INTO goodsandcat (Category, Goods) VALUES ('Electronics', 'Smartphones');




This was a good answer to a question that was clearly from someone who doesn't understand databases (as was the other answer), but mine can help that person with a solution.  Not sure why it was marked -1; maybe because the question is being closed? Seems like there needs to be a better system when a good answer is given to a weak question.

=IF is not valid SQL

@RobDogoSpahitz I didn't vote on your answer, but it makes the impression you don't understand databases or at least SQL, too. A column does not contain any formula, it just holds data. Furthermore, there is no =IF... in SQL. And a string NULL makes no sense. NULL indicates there is no value in this column and this row. You can check if a column in a row IS NULL or not, it's not a string you will compare with another.

Frank Heiken and @JonasMetzler, you didn't read the whole comment.  The SQL was there; the =IF is how you could ("drop it into a spreadsheet" to) produce the SQL that would give the desired answer.  As for the NULL, it was not clear from the question if the result was the string 'NULL' or a null value (which would require a modified version of the INSERT command.)

Many thanks for the answers. So, it was a sample of a small data from database where categories and their respective goods stored in the same column. The task is to divide this column by two which the first one will consist only from Goods and the second one will reflect Good's categories in each row.
I was wondered how is possible to do it using the Key. I understand that no direct relationsheeps between goods and categories, so that is why I post this example here for a possible solutions.
Thank you @Rob Dogo Spahitz, it is usefull, doable and works properly!

There is no relation between the Electronics and goods ,Clothing and clothing items you can change Electronics to 0 and Electronics items to 1 similarly clothing to 2 and clothing items to 3 then change your sql query accodingly.
